# Request Body with String Interpoloation

Tags: c#, string, string-interpolation

I have a Post API that contains the following Request Body

```json
{
      "format": "csv",
      "compress": "false",
      "startDate":"2023-07-25T00:00:00Z"
}
```

here is my code, my variable is returning correclty but i can't get the String Interpolation set up correctly please help!

```
var strStartDateZulu = strStartDate+"Z";
return await MakeApiCallAsync("RequestFileAsync", string.Empty, HttpMethod.Post, $"{\"format\":\"csv\", \"compress\":\"false\", \"startDate\":\"{strStartDateZulu}\"}", false);
```

Comment: That isn't sufficient information. What were you trying to do? What did you try to do? What were you expecting?

Comment: You should escape curly braces: `$"{{something}}"`. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated#special-characters

Comment: Did you want the request to literally be ```"startDate":"{strStartDateZulu}"```?

Comment: @001 thats exactly what i needed if you'd like to provide that as the answer ill be happy to gvie you credit thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally I would just use serialization with anonymous object, i.e. something like the following:

```cs
var request = JsonSerializer.Serialize(new
{
    format = "csv",
    compress = "false",
    startDate = strStartDateZulu
});
```

But if you are keen on using string interpolation you will need to use [double curly braces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated#special-characters) to escape curly braces in the interpolated string:

```cs
var request = $"{{\"format\":\"csv\", \"compress\":\"false\", \"startDate\":\"{strStartDateZulu}\"}}";
```

Also since C# 11 you also can use [raw string literals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-11.0/raw-string-literal):

```cs
var request = $$"""
{
    "format":"csv",
    "compress": "false",
    "startDate": "{{strStartDateZulu}}"
}             
""";
```